# How to add a new app to Available Apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do I add a newly acquired app to a host named site collection?

Through much effort, I managed to enable the App Store for a SharePoint app catalog. After installation, using the Central Administration\Apps\Purchase Apps feature, I "purchased" a trial license from the SharePoint store.

The app appears in Central Administration\Apps\Manage App Licenses but no where else. I expected it to appear in Central Administration\Apps\Manage App Catalog but nothing is there. is there a place to view all apps?

My ultimate goal is to make the app available in a host named site collection so that when I use Add App from the settings menu, I can add the app to the site collection. How is this possible? What do I need to do to make it visible in the host site?

SharePoint 2013 SP1 Enterprise, Windows Server 2012 R2, SQL server 2012, Farm

Comment: From App Catalog have you added the app?

Comment: there are 3 boxes in the App Catalog - 2 for distributing apps and 1 for managing requests. when I click Distribute apps for SharePoint, a dialog opens requesting a file to upload. I have no idea where the sharepoint store put the application, but it claimed it installed it when I acquired it from the SharePoint store. the apps store system is grotesquely designed. it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: i think i may have the store misconfigured.

Comment: i believe that my site is configured correctly - i was able to "purchase" an app. however, i cannot add an app from the web application's site collection. since app store service is application scoped, i would think that site collections would have the add app capability. instead, i get the message, Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps. and i don't see where to enable the capability for the site collection - it's already configured for the web application.